# java.net.BindException: Address already in use when running puppetdb and jira

Tags: postgresql, puppet

I'm trying to run both jira and puppetdb both on the same server using the same postgresql database. When I enable jira first, puppetdb throws the following error:

```
$sudo /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/puppet resource service puppetdb ensure=running enable=true
^[[1;31mError: Systemd start for puppetdb failed!
journalctl log for puppetdb:
-- Logs begin at Thu 2017-08-31 09:42:48 BST, end at Fri 2017-09-01 20:02:16 BST. --
Sep 01 19:57:34 techserver puppetdb[767]: java.net.BindException: Address already in us
```

What is causing the conflict? Something relating to the java stack or  postgresql itself?

Comment: `lsof -nPi` to see what is listening to which port. Then you can see what is actually listening on the port your are trying to bind to.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the default ports used by jira and puppet are 8080 and 8081. You can change the default ports used by puppet by editing the /etc/puppetlabs/puppetdb/conf.d/jetty.ini file. For example:

```
[jetty]
port = 9090
ssl-port = 9091
```